# How do you get an interface array (Dynamic Proxy)

Tags: java, interface, dynamic-proxy

I'm pretty confused on dynamic proxies.  I understand that I need a ProxyCreator class that will have a interfaceArray variable.  I am just not sure how I would go about creating an interface arrau.  Also, can I get a simple explanation for how to do a dynamic proxy.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way:

```
Closeable c = (Closeable) java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(
    getClass().getClassLoader(),
    new Class[]{ Closeable.class },
    new MyHandler(obj));

// works! by MyHandler is called instead.
c.close();
```

So the required interfaces are passed as an array of classes, and MyHandler is InvocationHanlder, taking delegate object `obj` as a parameter (if needed).

It all described [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html).